# can't make a new record after delete data on php

Tags: php

im newbie here, i have a trouble like this.

table: nota

no_nota(pk) name  addres

D01      xxx   xxxx

D02      xxx   xxxx

D03      xxx   xxxx

when im delete no_nota "D02" then i want to make new record, no_nota should be D04. but in my case no_nota be D03 not D04. my syntax code like this.

`<td>No Nota : </td>
    <td><?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nota");
    $data=(mysql_num_rows($sql)+1); 
        ?>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo "$data"; ?>" name="no_nota" required/><b></b>
    </td>`

someone how can tell me the right syntax? sory for my bad english
regards,

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to store your `no_nota` at all. Using an [auto-increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) from the database, you will always have the correct number and you can build your `no_nota` on the fly.

After inserting in the database of course. Technically you could query for the next auto-increment number but that will get you into a race condition if multiple users are using the system at the same time.